# Skype connection for multiple network

Tags: skype-for-business

We have a case in which we want to access Skype for Business. But the local laptop in which Skype is installed, have two network connection Con1 and Con2. And our requirement is Skype should connect it's server via CON2 only. Anyone let me know how to configure it.

Thanks